# Array that will stop asking from input after -1 is entered ( do not print the -1)

Tags: c

Im working on a an Array, rather simple infact that will allow a user to enter 5 numbers and then print that array, this much i have gotten to work, however there is a second condition that can be met when the user inputs -1, which will cause the Array to print based on the numbers currently enter but should include the -1, i cannot seem to get this to occur, this is my code : currently it does everything i need but still prints that -1 any help would be much appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARR 5

main() {
    int i = 0;
    int arr[ARR];

    for (i = 0; i < ARR; i++)
    {
        printf(" Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%i", &arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf(" the Numbers in the array are %i : ", i);

    for (i = 0; i < ARR; i++) {
        printf("\n %i, %i", i, arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Think about the process flow first, then code. Before you insert the number on the array, you need to check if its -1, and only if it's not, you should insert it. On the example you are first inserting and performing the check after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `if` condition earlier so that it checks for -1 first before printing.

```
if (arr[i] == -1) {
  break;
}
printf("\n %i, %i", i, arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind all that and sorry for using the wrong tag, i figured out 
         what i did wrong is was the order of the code i moved the printf statement out 
        of the for loop

```
    for (i = 0; i < ARR; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
        printf("\n %i, %i", i, arr[i]);
    }
     and now its working as intended. Someday i hope to able to post more here and 
     help others right now im just a noob learning as i go.
```